# What protocol does WP7 use to connect to mobile only "exchange" servers

Tags: windows-phone-7, exchange-server

As the question says, what protocol does Windows Phone (and similar platforms) use to connect to mobile only exchange servers, such as m.google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the [Exchange ActiveSync protocol](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/intellectualproperty/iplicensing/programs/exchangeactivesyncprotocol.aspx), documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28v=EXCHG.%2080%29.aspx). (Note that as it's a protocol, that means it doesn't actually have to talk to Exchange servers... just servers which speak the same protocol.)

(As an aside, the quality of client support for this protocol is, um, variable. Some phones have a very interesting idea of what constitutes valid time zone information.)

Comment: When you say `interesting idea` is that just a client issue, or is it that the server sends the time information in a silly way?

Comment: @cgoddard: No, it's that some clients send broken time zone information which doesn't conform to the specifications even slightly.