# Does WP7 email client use ActiveSync

Tags: c#, .net, email, windows-phone-7, exchange-server

I'm trying to develop a WP7 app that will download email periodically from exchange server. I was planning to use WP7 schedule task for this, but it doesn't execute in each interval. So wanted to know how WP7 email client talk to exchange server?

Is there any API/SDK available for Activesync to use in WP7.

--Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688458/what-protocol-does-wp7-use-to-connect-to-mobile-only-exchange-servers

Comment: Why are you trying to download email, when the built in services will do this per the end user's schedule? It sounds like you're trying to do something you don't need to - if you want to interact with their inbox, and provide a custom UI, you may be better off doing that instead of reimplementing all of the mail functionality in an app specific manner.

Answer (score 0):

No, Microsoft did not provide the APIs to third-party developers.

Answer (score 0):

for now there is no API to exchange ews for windows phone. But on the exchange server you can create your own web service using EWS Managed API

[Click here fore more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633696%20%28v%20=%20EXCHG.80%29.%20aspx)

and on the windows phone use this Web Service

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented same way. But EWS doesn't help to get email from gmail/hotmail. So for these email accounts I need Pop3/IMAP libaries and for individual email I have to give separate treatment. Is there any universal solution?